# duplicity can't find remote backup directory?

Tags: ssh, backup, sftp, scp, duplicity

Using my private key to do so, this command allows me to connect to /home/backupUser/backup just fine:

```
$ sudo sftp -oPort=7843 backupUser@192.168.x.x:backup
```

---

However when I run duplicity, I get the following error:

```
duplicity full --exclude ... / scp://backupUser:passwd@192.168.x.x:7843:/backup 

bash: wd@192.168.x.x:7843./backup: No such file or directory
```

I'm under the assumption that `duplicity` would interpret the `/backup` path as relative to the user's home directory.

But since the above command didn't work, I also tried leaving off the `/` in the backup directory at the end of the command, i.e.

```
duplicity full --exclude ... / scp://backupUser:passwd@192.168.x.x:7843:backup 
bash: wd@192.168.x.x:7843:backup: command not found
```

Is there something I'm missing here, like adding the passcode for the private key to make this command work?

Comment: I'm using duplicity 0.6.15 if that's of any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove : in your command. Please refer [**here**](http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/docs.html)

Comment: Okay so I changed the command to `duplicity --exclude ... / scp:/backupUser:passwd@192.168.x.x:7843//home/backupUser/backup` and I still get the same error of 
`pw@192.168.2.251:7843//home/backupUser/backup: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

since your are using bash i assume you want to connect to a linux user, you should try to append the ~ sing before the /directory , it is in order to go into the users home directory.

i know it should be like that automaticly, since you are try to connect the backup user, but as i can see in you question the two ansers you are getting from bash are diefferent, one is with ./backup and the other is :backup, so i think that you should try with the ~ sign.

Comment: Tried the command as `duplicity --exclude ... / scp:/backupUser:passwd@192.168.x.x:7843~/backup`

and I still get the same error of 
`pw@192.168.2.251:7843~/backup: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

> I'm under the assumption that duplicity would interpret the /backup
>   path as relative to the user's home directory.

Right. But the syntax is different than the normal `scp` format. Remove the colon and try again:

`duplicity full --exclude ... / scp://backupUser:passwd@192.168.x.x:7843/backup`

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out...thanks for all your help!

I tried an sftp command on it's own, and noticed that I was getting the same error (`No such file or directory`) whenever I left out the `-oPort` argument.

```
#An sftp command I tried on it's own...
#sftp -oIdentityFile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa -oPort=7843 -oServerAliveInterval=15 -oServerAliveCountMax=2 buser@192.168.2.251
```

I made the changes to the path suggested by @Sivaram Kannan above, and added the `-oPort` argument to the `--ssh-options`, and that seemed to fix the problem:

```
sudo duplicity   --ssh-askpass --dry-run  --num-retries 1 --ssh-options="-oPort=7843 -oIdentityFile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa" \
 --exclude /proc --exclude /tmp --exclude /mnt --exclude /dev --exclude /sys \
--force / scp://buser@192.168.x.x:7843//home/backupUser/backup
```

(And of course the `--dry-run` parameter keeps it from running just testing it out)

Seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Although in the risk of getting -1, I want to clarify on the common mistakes we make on duplicity format (which the original question has made).

We commonly forget the second "//" in the host for example:

```
duplicity full --exclude ... / scp://backupUser:passwd@192.168.x.x:7843:backup
```

The error is that (although somebody has indicated that it should be not be ":") the format should be:

```
duplicity full --exclude ... / scp://backupUser:passwd@192.168.x.x:7843//backup
```

I commonly forget to use the "//" (although for me, I get different errors).